# Swift remove from parent controller with completion

Tags: swift, completion, parentviewcontroller

I know that in Swift, when dismissing a view controller, I have the option to run some code in a completion block. I.e.

```
controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    // code
})
```

Can something like this be done when removing a view controller from its parent view controller? I'm running the following code:

```
controller.removeFromParentViewController()
```

And I would like to call something after that's completed. Thanks!

Comment: You are working with transitionFromViewController?

Comment: `removeFromParentViewController` is synchronous, therefore it does not need a completion block. If you are using an animation, use the completion block of the animation.